# Explicit Casting operator and Polymorphism

Tags: java, polymorphism

I have a small issue with polymorphism and explicit casting.
Here is the problem:
I have 3 public classes:

```
  package x;

public class Shape
{
 public void draw(){
     System.out.println("draw a Shape");
 }
}

package x;

public class Circle1 extends Shape
{

}

package x;

public class Circle2 extends Circle1
{
    @Override
    public void draw ()
    {
       System.out.println("draw Circle2");
    }
}
```

And my Demo class is:

```
package x;

public class Demo
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        Shape s1=new Circle2();
        s1.draw();
        ((Shape)s1).draw();

    }
}
```

The output of this code is:

> draw Circle2
>   draw Circle2

I understand the polymorphic behavior of `s1.draw()` that invokes the `draw()` method on `Circle2`.
The last line confuses me, when I do explicit casting on s1 like so: `((Shape)s1)`, it means that the expression  `((Shape)s1)` is a reference of type Shape because of the explicit casting,right?
And if that is so, why then the code  `((Shape)s1).draw();` invokes the `draw()` method in `Circle2` and not the one in Shape?

Thanks  :)

Comment: `s1` already has type `Shape`...so the cast doesn't have any sense

Answer (score 3):

**Casting** does not change what the object **is**, it simply changes how the compiler should **look at** that object.

So even if you "think" of a Circle to be "just a shape" it still stays a Circle.

The only way for a `Circle1` to call `Shape`'s draw would be from *within* `Circle1` by a call to `super.draw()`

Answer (score 0):

When you explicitly (or implicitly) cast an object to a super type the methods will always obey the implementation of the class used to construct the object. In your case, because your object was constructed with `new Circle2()`, it will always be a Circle2, even if you cast it. In fact, there is an easy way for you to see that. Just add the following lines to your code:

```
Shape s2 = (Shape) s1;
System.out.println(s2.getClass().getName());
```

This prints the exact class that your `s2` object (casted from s1) belongs to :) you will see it is still a Circle2.

If you want to call the super type implementation of the `draw()` method you need to call `super.draw()` instead.